# JScrollPane does not show its content (JTable)

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I am working on something like an IT Manager Tool to store data about pcs, notebooks, server, ... based on a MySQL database.

My problem:
The JScrollPane does not show the JTable. 
I have already tried to add JButton instead, which is also not being showed. 
Already googled and found some ideas with table.revalidate() but nothing helped so far.

Here is my code:

class "Gui":

```
package ManageIT;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/**
 * @author a.struck
 *
 */
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1287952773890821788L;

    private static DatabaseConnection dbSettings = new DatabaseConnection();
    public static Gui main;
    private ComputerList computerList;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private String ipAddress;
    private String port;
    private String database;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main = new Gui();
        dbSettings.loadConnection();
    }

    /**
     * initialize Gui
     */
    public Gui() {
        // initialize gui and its behavior
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // menu bar
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // computer list
        JMenuItem computerMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Computers");
        computerMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickedAbout) {
                // create new computerList
                computerList = new ComputerList();
                computerList.initializeMain(main);
                loadDatabase(dbSettings.getDatabaseConnection(), "computers");
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(computerMenuItem);

        // database settings
        JMenuItem mItemDatabase = new JMenuItem("Connect Database");
        mItemDatabase.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                dbSettings.loadConnection();
                dbSettings.initializeDatabaseSettingsGui();
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(mItemDatabase);

        // initialize scroll pane where the tables will be placed on
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setSize(1600, 768);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Returns scrollPane, where the computerList is placed on
     * 
     * @return JScrollPane
     */
    public JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public void loadDatabase(String[] connection, String function) {
        ipAddress = connection[0];
        port = connection[1];
        database = connection[2];
        user = connection[3];
        password = connection[4];

        try {
            // load driver
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to load driver.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // open connection
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + "/" + database
                    + "?" + "user=" + user + "&" + "password=" + password);
            // create statement
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            if (function == "computers") {
                // create querie
                String sqlCommand = "SELECT internal_id, user, state, product_name, serial_number, operating_system, harddrive, ram, cpu, date_purchased, date_installed, ip_address, network_plug, teamviewer_id, notes FROM computer";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlCommand);
                computerList.initializeComputers(rs);

            }

            // close statement
            stmt.close();
            // close connection
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + sqle.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + sqle.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + sqle.getErrorCode());
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

class "ComputerList":
note: the String values[][] were for test purposes, but the MySQL connection works fine.

```
package ManageIT;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @author a.struck
 *
 */

public class ComputerList {

    public static Gui main;

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public ComputerList() {
    }

    public void initializeMain(Gui x) {
        main = x;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new table
     * 
     */
    public void initializeComputers(ResultSet rs) {

        // remove all components of the panel
        main.getScrollPane().removeAll();

        // create table
        String header[] = { "Internal ID", "User", "State", "Product Name", "Serial Number", "Operating System",
                "Harddrive", "RAM", "CPU", "Date Purchased", "Date Installed", "IP Address", "Network Plug",
                "Teamviewer ID", "Notes" };

        String values[][] = { { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" },
                { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" } };

        JTable table = new JTable(values, header);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "Internal ID", "User", "State", "Product Name",
                "Serial Number", "Operating System", "Harddrive", "RAM", "CPU", "Date Purchased", "Date Installed",
                "IP Address", "Network Plug", "Teamviewer ID", "Notes" }, 0);

        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                model.addRow(new Object[] { rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4),
                        rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9),
                        rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14),
                        rs.getString(15) });
            }
            table.setModel(model);

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + sqle.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + sqle.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + sqle.getErrorCode());
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        main.getScrollPane().setViewportView(table);

        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having same problems, I now found out the the table is not being showed due to the "scrollPane.removeAll()" as this seems to remove something from the scroll pane that is needed to show the table. Going to check this out now. Question can be closed.